# can't open non english .vi files (lv2013)

Tags: labview

Is there any way to open  xyz.vi ( xyz = non English) files?
that is what happen when i am trying to open  my main.vi file - it searches the non English .vi although they are in the same folder:
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUCeS.jpg)

Comment: I think this may be a better question asked of National Instruments tech support instead of StackOverflow. This is not so much a "How do I do this?" question as a bug fix question. ni.com/forums

Answer (score 1):

Simply click "Browse" and select the VI. I'm not sure that the search function supports Unicode characters, but you should be able to load it manually.

Comment: "...the file '???? ???.vi' could not be loaded "
for every .vi that in the  same folder i choose.

Comment: Can you try renaming them the UTF8 file names? It may give a warning that something loaded from a different path but that's okay. Just click ignore.

Answer (score 1):

changing the system locale (to my language) solved it.